# dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, refactoring

I have the following code for attempting to dequeue an annotation view and then creating one if it doesn't exist but there is a bit of duplication and this doesn't seem like the "swift" way. Any suggestions on how to improve upon this?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    let identifier = "annotation"

    if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
        configureAnnotationView(annotationView)

        return annotationView
    } else {
        let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        configureAnnotationView(annotationView)

        return annotationView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

One way to shorten it would be perhaps

```
let annotationView = 
   mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)  ??
   MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
```

Then you would also only need one `return` statement and no `if` clause.